# Call a public bool as a public void

Tags: c#

I have an issue I would like to do a public bool in a public class and call it as a void.

I would like to check if the bool in a second class is true or not.

For example in my first class:

```
public class GetWindow
{
   public string Check { get; set; } 

   public bool checkwindow()
   {
       if (Listofwindows.Contains(Check))
         return true;
       else
         return false;
   }
}
```

And the second one:

```
public Form1()
{ [...]

  GetWindow myprogram1 = new GetWindow();
  myprogram1.Check = "Kin"; 

  if (myprogram1.checkwindow == true) 
        {/*Do thing*/}
}
```

> Obvisouly it doesn't work because of `myprogram1.checkwindow` it says:
>
> Cannot convert method group 'checkwindow' to non-delegate type bool

"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'group of methods' and 'bool'

Because of `myprogram1.checkwindow == true`.

So it seems dead to do it this way but i have no idea no idea how to do it differently! (i need my getwindow class.)

Comment: You need `if (myprogram1.checkwindow() == true)`.  Note the extra pair of brackets.

Comment: You forgot the parentheses `()` I think: `myprogram1.checkwindow() == true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to call a method in C#, you need to add parenthesis after the method name, even when the method does not expect parameters:

```
if (myprogram1.checkwindow() == true) 
{
        {/*Do thing*/}
}
```

Also, to evaluate boolean values you do not need to compare with the literal `true`. You can just write:

```
if (myprogram1.checkwindow()) 
{
        {/*Do thing*/}
}
```

Comment: Ok when they said "don't forget the parenthesis i didn't thought of these ones. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the useless property and pass a parameter to the `checkwindow` method. Something like

```
public class GetWindow
{

   public bool checkwindow(string check)
   { 
       // Contains already returns true/false, no need of additional checks
       return Listofwindows.Contains(check);
   }
}
```

and call it with

```
public Form1()
{ [...]

    GetWindow myprogram1 = new GetWindow();
    if (myprogram1.checkwindow("Kin")) 
    {/*Do thing*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

optimize :

```
public class GetWindow
{
   public string Check { get; set; }   
   public bool checkwindow()
      {
         return Listofwindows.Contains(Check);
      }

}
```

And cal it :

```
 GetWindow myprogram1 = new GetWindow();
 myprogram1.Check = "Kin"; 

if (myprogram1.checkwindow()) 
{
        {/*Do thing*/}
}
```